# Toggle Button doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I'm sure I've written this code properly as I followed in the tutorial. I want the #booking-button to be clicked which should 'toggle' the #btn element to disappear. Essentially one is a box which contains information about a car and when user clicks 'Click here to Book' it should open the form. But for some reason it doesn't. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the CSS but I'm not sure.

Any tips on this?

```html
          <div class="form-wrapper">
                <form action="#">
                    <label for="name">Name*</label>
                    <input placeholder="Your Name" class="full" type="text"id="name">
                    <br>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input placeholder="Your Email" class="full" type="text"id="name">
                    <br>
                    <label for="hire-start-date">Hire Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="depart">
                    <br>
                    <label for="hire-end-date">Hire End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="depart">
                    <br>
               
                    <button class="book-now">Book Now</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="car-info" id="btn">  
                <button id="booking-button">Click Here to Book</button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#booking-button').on('click', () => 
    { $('#btn').toggle(); });

});
```

Comment: As you are going to hide the parent div of the button that means user won't be able to click on that button again, I would recommend you to use the hide() function for that instead of toggle() function.

Comment: I tried both hide and toggle but none seems to be working. What I did instead was just use opacity to close the car-info div

Comment: Can you post your whole code with CSS, it may give more clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I did try the hide function but still didnt seem to work.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? I am not having clarity on your question, as you said there might be some CSS issue, if that's the case I need to see CSS as well

Comment: Hi I managed to fix it. I instead used the display.none function! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Now the form appears when user clicks `Click Here to Book`, while this button disappears.

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="#" id="car-info" style="display: none;">
      <label for="name">Name*</label>
      <input placeholder="Your Name" class="full" type="text"id="name">
      <br>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input placeholder="Your Email" class="full" type="text"id="name">
      <br>
      <label for="hire-start-date">Hire Start Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="depart">
      <br>
      <label for="hire-end-date">Hire End Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="depart">
      <br>

      <button class="book-now">Book Now</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="btn">  
  <button id="booking-button">Click Here to Book</button>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#booking-button').on('click', () => {
      $('#car-info').toggle();
      $('#btn').toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```